# applescript - how to improve this script

Tags: macos, optimization, applescript, automator, lossless-compression

First thing first, this is my first attempt of using applescript, so please be patient :)

**What i'm trying to achieve:** I am using dropbox as a way to store some picture online. I almost used all the availabe space, but today i realised that with a simple lossless optimisation on jpgs i can save up to 35-40% of space (I optimised everything using an app). So my idea here is: since dropbox on my mac runs in the background everytime and if i add something (or camera uploads from the phone) the picture will eventually reach a folder in my mac, so, maybe, i can monitor that folder, optimise the picture automatically and the it gets uploaded again because as far as DP is concerned, the picture is different, and i will end up with automatically optimised images.

**Steps so far:**

- Find a CLI to optimse images ✔️
- Create a service based on a folder, that runs everytime something changes in the folder ✔️
- Optimise the images ✔️
- Show a notification once done ✔️

The automator script looks like this (attached to a test folder for now):

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        do script with command "imageoptim --directory /Users/Nick/Desktop/untitled"
    end tell
end run
```

and this actually works, well, more or less.

I'd like to improve this as i'm not 100% happy with the way it works.

At the moment, if i add/rename a picture, a terminal window opens (sometimes 2 terminal windows), the command is exectuted and then that's it. It never cloeses, and also the notification is triggered as soon as the terminal window opens, and not once the optimisation is completed.

**How i'd like to improve it:**

- First of all, I don't want the terminal window to open. Ideally, nothing should open at all. It should just execute the optimisation and that's it.
- The notification should show some useful message and it should open only after the compression (as a callback from the script, basically) but i don't know how to wait for a callback
- Ideally, the notification should show previous size and new size. I searched for a way to get the folder size, but there was nothing in automator that i could use. My idea was to get previous folder size and add it to a variable, run everything, get new folder size, another variable and print the variables as notification message, but i don't know, as i said, how to get folder size.

Can you give me a hand or even point me to some useful resources?
Of (even better) is something similar already exists and i'm just trying to reinvent the wheel, please let me know :)

thanks in advance

**EDIT**

I found this: https://www.alfredforum.com/topic/3703-imageoptim-workflow/ and it does pretty much all i want. Is it possible to convert from Alfred wordkflow to pure automator workflow?

Comment: Please be aware that JPEG optimisation is practically never lossless. Also, if you don't want the Terminal to show up, just use `do shell script` rather than telling the Terminal to activate.

Answer (score 1):

I saved this script in scripteditor as an application.  So the way this is set now is all I need to do is drag Image files onto the icon of the application which triggers the script.  You can change this and use the script as a folder action or however else you want

```
on open files_list
    (*
scale v : Scale an image
scale specifier : the object for the command
[by factor real] : scale using a scalefactor
[to size integer] : scale using a max width/length
*)
    set max_size to "600" as integer -- use the above commented code to play around with scaling.  My example scaled everything to a width of 600 pixels proportionately
    set output_folder to alias "Macintosh HD:Users:Smokestack:Desktop:untitled folder:" -- create an alias to whatever folder you want
    tell application "System Events" to get the size of output_folder
    set originalSize to the result
    set n2 to "1,000,000" as integer
    set originalSize to originalSize / n2
    repeat with file_ref in files_list
        try
            tell application "Image Events"
                set the_image to open file_ref
                scale the_image to size max_size
                save the_image in file ((output_folder as text) & name of the_image)
                close the_image
            end tell
        on error error_string
            display dialog "Skipping file " & (file_ref as text) & ¬
                " due to error:" & error_string buttons {"OK"} default button 1
        end try
    end repeat
    tell application "System Events" to get the size of output_folder
    set newSize to the result
    set newSize to newSize / n2
    display dialog "The Original Folder Size Is " & originalSize & " Megabytes" & linefeed & "The New Folder Size Is " & newSize & " Megabytes" with title "FOLDER INFORMATION" buttons {"OK"} default button 1 giving up after 10
end open
```